# how to calculate power value

Tags: r, statistics

I have simulated data in R and conducted a 2-sample t-test (2-sided hypothesis). I assumed an alpha value of 0.05, calculated p-values to determine if I accept or reject the null hypothesis. I need to now calculate power for each data set and plot. I need help on how to calculate power when alpha is known.
More info on my data: I have 100 datasets of sample- `rnorm(100,mean1,sd1)` for each sample1 and sample 2.

Example data:

```r
sample1 <- replicate(100,rnorm(100,0,1))
sample2 <- replicate(100,rnorm(100,5,3))
```

Comment: Have you looked at the function `power.t.test()` ?

Answer (score 3):

I **think** you mean something like this:

### extract a vector of p-values by running the test for each set of samples

```r
alpha <- 0.05
nsim <- 100
set.seed(101)
sample1 <- replicate(nsim, rnorm(100,0,1))
sample2 <- replicate(nsim, rnorm(100,5,3))
pvalues <- rep(NA, nsim)
for (i in 1:nsim) {
   tt <- t.test(sample1[,i], sample2[,i]
   pvalues[i] <- tt$p.value
}
```

### compute power (proportion of the time that p<alpha)

You can do this with `sum(pvalues<alpha)/nsim`, but

```r
mean(pvalues<alpha)
```

is slightly more compact. (`pvalues < alpha` is `TRUE` or `FALSE`; applying a numeric function like `sum()` or `mean()` to it converts `FALSE` to 0 and `TRUE` to 1; taking the mean computes the *proportion* of values for which `pvalues < alpha`, which is exactly the observed probability of rejecting the null hypothesis → power.

As @neilfws points out, you can find the power for a t-test much more efficiently with `power.t.test()` (however, simulation is still useful for handling unusual cases that don't fit into the standard framework).